# Access to atmosphere's packages list

Tags: meteor, meteorite

I would like to know if is there any way I can read the whole list of packages atmosphere handles or any sort of list of available packages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean you want to see what packages your app is using run this in your apps directory

```
meteor list --using
```

If you mean you want to access the raw data on atmosphere you can do this using DDP.

The data is stored in the `packages` collection & you can access it by subscribing to `packageMetadata`

If you use meteor you can do (Server side)

```
var atmosphere = DDP.connect("https://atmosphere.meteor.com");
atmosphere.subscribe("packageMetadata");

var Packages = new Meteor.Collection("packages", {connection: atmosphere});
```

Once the subscription is complete you can view the packages in the `Packages` collection.

This isn't limited to using meteor there are DDP modules available in other languages such as [.NET](https://github.com/sonyarouje/DDPClient.NET), [Nodejs](https://github.com/oortcloud/node-ddp-client) & [ruby](https://github.com/tmeasday/ruby-ddp-client) to name a few

Comment: Nice, that's what I needed. The server side thing. Maybe the question wasn't clear enough. Thx!

Comment: Hi Akshat, in your comment to the person asking for help with two Mongodb databases and Meteor http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535755/using-multiple-mongodb-databases-with-meteor-js, you say it can't be done at the present time. But aren't you doing something like that with this subscribing to packageMetadata?

Comment: @tonemcd this is same method used in the answer there in the first part. A different database can't be used with the same app, but if there is a seperate meteor app with another db it can be connected to that one to make it appear as a different database.

Answer (score 0):

go to your app dir and type meteor list/mrt list