# meteorjs use external mongoDb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I found a few posts on stackoverflow with the same question but i do not understand what to do - and if i understood it it does not work for me.

Maybe its important to know tht i am using **Windows**.

The Problem:

I develope an meteorJs App on my local machine. Now i have a external mongoDB host and i want to connect my Application to this host, so the data for the collection in my app will be get from the external database.

The mongoDb host give me a link like this:

```
mongodb://.....:.....@dbs004.......com/my_db_name
```

So i have the link. And now ? Is there any JavaScript file i can include to my /server dir to define the mongoDb Url ?

Comment: Check this post out: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535755/using-multiple-mongodb-databases-with-meteor-js>  The answer contains an option to connect to a custom mongodb connection.

Comment: This looks interesting. i will test it.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the `MONGO_URL` environment variable as described in the deployment section of the documentation. So in your case you can start meteor as follows, or set the environment variable in some other way first before starting meteor:

```
MONGO_URL=mongodb://.....:.....@dbs004.......com/my_db_name meteor $@
```