# Using a different collection for users in Meteor

Tags: mongodb, postgresql, meteor

I have a Meteor project which I have unfortunately been forced to modify to use PostgreSQL instead of MongoDB, through the package `meteorsteam:meteor-postgres`. I have managed to get everything sorta working, except the `users` collection, which appears to be welded together with Meteor.

Is it possible to use some other collection for it?

I have tried replacing it with an in-memory-collection `Meteor.users = new Meteor.Collection(null)`, and hooking up some logic to sync it with a psql table. This messes up the built-in publish-functions, since the collection doesn't have a name.

There will not be a lot of users, so having the whole thing in memory as a meteorcollection is not a problem.

I have searched around the internet, but couldn't find anything even mentioning it.

Suggestions?

Comment: Could you [use mongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535755/using-multiple-mongodb-databases-with-meteor-js/20537457#20537457) just for the `users` table?

Comment: MongoDB is not an option at all, unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

If you can, an easy solution is to use MongoDB just for your users table:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  var database = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/your_mongodb_base");
  Meteor.users = new Mongo.Collection("users", { _driver: database });
}
```

Actually, since `meteor-postgres` does not use `Mongo.Collection` but `SQL.Collection`, you may even get away with just:

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  Meteor.users = new Mongo.Collection("users");
}
```