# How to connect a Meteor site to an existing db & collection?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I have server & client files and am trying to send some data to Javascript rather than into a template. In the template, I can output some values, but I need it in JS to add markers to Leaflet.

I guess, there's no sense to funnel the data through templates to get it into JS and into Leaflet, right?

What am I doing wrong?

**shell**

```
$ mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.4.9
connecting to: test
> use atms
switched to db atms
> db.markers.count()
1868
```

Running the server:

```
$ MONGO_URL=mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/atms meteor
```

**lib/collections.js**

```
Markers = new Meteor.Collection('markers');
```

In the **client/client.js**, I try to get records from the collection, but it's empty:

```
Template.hello.helpers({
    marks: function () {
        // this data renders correctly on map
        return Markers.findOne({})
    }
});

Template.hello.onRendered(function() {
    // this data is empty in console
    var query = Markers.find().fetch();
    console.log(query);
});
```

In the template, it shows one record, which means the connection works. But console output is `[]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is you have 2 different `Markers` collection on client and server. So, on the client, `meteor` accesses client Marker collections and does not show any data. Collection definition should be shared between client and server, not duplicated.

Make a folder `lib` and put the collection definitions there

```
//lib/collections.js
Markers = new Mongo.Collection('markers')
```

And remove the collection definitions in both `server` and `client` folder.

Also, be aware that when you use the separated `mongo` instance, the reactivity will happen quite slow (2 or 3 times compared to the embedded `mongo`)

Comment: The code kind of worked, without `var` keyword (otherwise Markers is again undefined). I restarted with `MONGO_URL`, no crashes, but still an empty collection.

Comment: sorry bout the `var`.  i copied/pasted your code and didnt see that.

Comment: I managed to push one record through the templates, but why `Markers.find().fetch()` does not show anything in console.log?

Comment: it takes times to return the data because you are using the separated mongo. Sorry, i just out for the meeting and just go back and see you mark answer as done. Thanks mate lol

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure this is answered here:

[Using Multiple Mongodb Databases with Meteor.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535755/using-multiple-mongodb-databases-with-meteor-js)

Just a note on the syntax, in ver 1.2.1 you want to declare your Meteor collection as a global variable so it can be accessed outside of the file you type it into.  Also, you want to put this line in /lib or a directory that can be accessed by both the client and server.

```
Markers = new Mongo.Collection('markers')
```

Comment: I don't get it. In `server.js` I run that connection with `_driver` and it seems to be ok. But in the `client.js` I leave it the same, and nothing changes, still an empty array.

If I remove `Marker` declaration from `client`, then it's undefined and js crashes. But I can't copy that `_driver` code, because `MongoInternals` isn't defined in cilent.