# How to create a new database in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

In the Meteor framework, is it possible to create two databases?

I have read the Meteor API document but I only found the collection operation. I also tried to search the google, however, I can't get anything useful.

I am confused how to create a new database and how to use it? Does Meteor support this?

Comment: yes you can..please check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535755/using-multiple-mongodb-databases-with-meteor-js)

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new meteor project (`meteor create my-project`) a new database is created for that project. Within this database you can create "collections" for you data.

If you want to use a different instance of mongo (the only currently supported database) you have to change the environment variables as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12996674/3032150), or if you want to use multiple mongo instances for different collections look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535755/using-multiple-mongodb-databases-with-meteor-js) that was mentioned in the comments on your question. That is a very advanced use case though!