# Meteor change database at run time

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

I have three database i.e, **main_db** it is default load database. I want load database after login.
Database are:-

**main_db**

->user_collection

**psm_2017_db**

->abc_collection

->xyz_collection

**psm_2018_db**

->abc_collection

->xyz_collection

Here is my project structure

[image]

here is my login script.

```
client
 |->login
  |->login.js

            Template.login.rendered = function(){
            SessionStore.set("login_user",false);
            };
            Template.login.events({
                'submit #formLogin': function (event, target){
                    event.preventDefault();
                    var email = target.find('#loginEmail').value;
                    var password = target.find('#loginPassword').value;
                    // console.log(email +" "+password);
                    Meteor.loginWithPassword(email, password, function(err){

                        if(err){
                        console.log(err);
                            alert("Invalid Login!");
                        }
                        else {
                        SessionStore.set("login_user",true);
                            console.log('successfully')
                            Router.go("/dashboard")
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

            Template.layout.helpers({
            "isLoggedin": function () {
                return SessionStore.get("login_user");
            }
            });
```

here is my load collection file

```
lib
 |->collection.js

     abcCollection=new Mongo.Collection("abc_collection");         
     xyzCollection=new Mongo.Collection("xyz_collection");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Multiple Mongodb Databases with Meteor.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535755/using-multiple-mongodb-databases-with-meteor-js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can connect to multiple dbs using the below approach.

```
var database = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver("<<mongo url>>");
MyCollection = new Mongo.Collection("collection_name", { _driver: database });
```

`<<mongo_url>>` is your standard mongodb url.
Eg. `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/database_name`

Now, in your specific scenario, `main_db` contains the user collection (I'm under the assumption that this is pertaining to meteor user collection). You need to have this loaded at all times. You can't have it load after login since user information - which is required for logging in resides in that db!

Once you take care of the above, connecting to the remaining two dbs can be done on login as below:

`/lib/dbconnection.js` (this will be common to both server and clinet)

```
Meteor.methods({
    loadDB: function(){

        if(Meteor.userId()){ // if a user has logged in

            var database = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver("<<mongo url>>");
            MyCollection = new Mongo.Collection("collection_name", { _driver: database });

        }


    }
})
Meteor.call("loadDB");
```

`loadDB` will get called each time a user logs in. But I fear that it will be run each time *any* user logs in. In order to avoid it being re-initialized for each user login, you might want to do a check on  whether `database` or `myCollection` already exists.

Comment: i want to load database dynamic. e.g 
 `mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/<dbNameVar>`

Comment: I suppose you can wrap it in a function and call it when the user logs in?  This will have to exist in common with the client and server.

Comment: yes, but how to do this. Because meteor load `lib` directory at startup phase.

Comment: Updated my answer addressing this.

Comment: when i refresh web page then this error `"Exception while invoking method 'loadDB' Error: There is already a collection named ...."` generate at server side. how to handle this

Comment: It's what I feared and explained in the last part of my answer. You can have only one instance of a collection declared. You will have to have something like an if block which checks to see if the collection is already existing. If it's not, only then, proceed to initialize the connection.